# Runway X Serverless Framework: Using runway for CICD to deploy with environment variables from serverless dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, dashboard, serverless-framework

I am using the SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY to login while using the CICD to access the environment variables, but I can't seem to be able to place the key in the correct place:

```
deployments:
  - modules:
      - path: api.sls
        environments:
          dev: true
        parameters:
          namespace: sls-${env DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT}
        options:
          extend_serverless_yml:
            custom:
              env:
                SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY: "AKmjWhDmsYcwmjNvek6mfsI046LoA1nlMhyaKpRvKFHLk"
    regions:
      - us-east-1
```

Question is: is this the correct place for the access key or should it be added in the serverless.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is figure out if Runway has a way for you to add an environment variable for the build container. The Serverless Framework looks for an environment variable called SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY to authenticate you to your Serverless account. From a quick Google it looks like this can be done using `env_vars` as a parameter in your config

Comment: That did the job, thank you! I was confused as to where the serverless framework needed to read it from.